# How to get n elements of a list starting at an index?

Tags: python

I regularly want the next `n` elements of a list starting from somewhere inside the list, instead of the front or back. Usually that looks like:

`my_elements = my_list[index: index + n]`

I don't like the verbosity of having to write `index` twice, however. Is there a pythonic way to say "give me the next n elements starting from here"?

Comment: `Is there a pythonic way to say "give me the next n elements starting from here"?` Yes, and it's exactly what you already have

Answer (score 2):

What you have would be considered "pythonic" but since you mentioned not wanting to repeat the word `index`, you *can* (but please don't) go this route:

```
>>> x = [20,40,80,160,320,640]
>>> index=2
>>> x[index: index+3]
[80, 160, 320]
>>> x[index:][:3]
[80, 160, 320]
```

Nice programming exercise, perhaps, but IMHO this is not pythonic (and in fact, unless a compiler can optimize this expression, it might be inefficient as well). It is okay to repeat the name in this case, I believe.

Comment: You can point out that a disadvantage of this code is that it creates 2 additional lists

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own type that was similar to a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#slice), but initialized differently:

```
class Section:
    def __new__(cls, start, length):
        return slice(start, start+length)

n = 3
index = 6
section = Section(index, n)

eban = [2, 4, 6, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 50]
print(eban[section])  # -> [36, 40, 42]

# Alternatively

print(eban[Section(index+1, n)])  # -> [40, 42, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** do not like having to reference `index` twice you could use this, but it's really an overkill and obviously less Pythonic. What you have now is the most idiomatic and Pythonic way possible to achieve what you want.

```
li = list(range(10))
index = 3
n = 4


li_iter = iter(li[index:])
print([next(li_iter) for _ in range(n)])
```

Outputs

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

If your just looking for a different way to do the same thing then here you go.

```
my_slice = slice(index, index+n)
my_elements = my_list[my_slice]
```

Not sure if there is any change in performance.

Comment: OP is "worried" by referencing `index` twice. This also does that

Comment: Yes that is true, but in the event that his index doesn't change, he can use the same slice as much as he wants.

Comment: But it still does not "solve" the "problem" OP is asking about